# Dynamic length of strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I've debugged some programs in C++ and I notice a difference between for instance :

```
char str[] = "It's a test";
```

But when you use string in `<string>` header, it seems that has a variable length and for instance, the following **is allowed**:

```
string str1 = "abcdefg";
str1 = "abc";
```

But this is **not allowed** :

```
char str[] = "It's a test";
str = "abc";
```

It won't work! What's the implementation behind that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can *initialize* an array, which is done with

```
char array[] = "some string literal";
```

but you can't *assign* to an array. That's just the rules of the language.

The [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class have a special overload for the assignment operator that allows it to be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

you thought that when at first you have initialised the array of characters and another time when you use it it is not needed to initialise again! but its not true...every time you declare and initialise any array and when ever you are using it again you have to do it again! for example:

```
char user[] = "sci3nt15t";
char user[] = "Ender";
```

its good for you to have a look at a definition of string and array.

hope it helps.